# using if else condition inside of echo in PHP

Tags: php

It throws some error if i try to simple place it inside echo.

The php code for echo is :

```html
echo "
<td height='280' width='240' align='center'>
  <img src='Product/$i' ] ' height='200 ' width='200 '><br/>
 
 <b>Item Name:</b>".$data['product_name '].
   "<br><b>Price:</b>Rs&nbsp;".$data['product_price '].
   "<br><b>Description:</b>".$data['product_description '].
   "<br><a href=#><img src='images/buy4.jpg ' width='100 ' height='50 '/></a>.
   
   </td>";
```

And I want to put the below condition inside it :

```js
if(isset($_GET['Currency']))
 {
 $Currency =  $_GET['currency'];// user selected currency
 if($Currency!="GBP")
 {
  if($Currency=="USD"){echo "$";}
  
 echo convertCurrency($pound_price, "GBP", $Currency);
 if($Currency=="EUR"){echo "&#8364";}
 
 }
 else {echo "&pound". $pound_price;}
 
 
 }
 else
 {
  echo "&pound". $pound_price;
  
 }
```

How can I do so ?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the variable before outputing the final result.

First you retrieve the get currency variable if available

```
$currency = isset($_GET['currency']) ? (string) $_GET['currency'] : '';
```

Then you can have a function that gives you the formatted output regarding the currency and the price :

```
function getFormattedPrice($currency, $price)
{
    $formattedPrice = '';
    switch($currency) {
        case 'USD' :
            $formattedPrice = $price . '$';
            break;
        case 'EUR' :
            $formattedPrice = $price . '&#8364';
            break;
        default :
            $formattedPrice = '&pound' . $price;
            break;
    }

    return $formattedPrice;
}
```

Then you can get your formatted price with this line

```
$formattedPrice = getFormattedPrice($currency, $pound_price);
```

And echo you text using the formatted value. Or call the function in your echo like this :

```
echo "<br>" . getFormattedPrice($currency, $data['product_price ']);
```